# Why do i get an expected expression error message when I am trying to get a value from a custom function

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I’ve been writing this code just for a school project most of it is good I think but when I try to compile it gives me an error message “error: expected expression” for 3 different lines each of which are calling a custom function. (I have PI and G set up as const values.

```
void create_table(double v)
{
  double angle,t,d;
  printf("\n\nAngle:\tTime:\tDistance\t\n");
  for(double deg=0.0; deg<=90.0; deg+=5.0)
  {
    angle = double degree_to_radian(deg);
    t = double Projectile_travel_time(angle, v);
    d = double Projectile_travel_distance(angle, v);
    printf("%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n",angle,t,d);
  }
}


double Projectile_travel_time(double a, double v)
{
  double t;
  t=2*v*sin(a)/G;
  return(t);
}


double Projectile_travel_distance(double a, double v)
{
  double d;
  d=pow(v,2)/G*sin(2*a);
  return(d);
}


double degree_to_radian(double d)
{
  double rad;
  rad = d*PI/180;
  return(rad);
}
```

The error is pointing to where I’m reassigning angle, d, and t and more specifically right at the ‘d’ of double. I've tried to define the other functions at the top, and I’ve tries removing the double in front, but nothing seems to have worked for me. If anyone can give me a pointer on what to do, I’d appreciate it.

Comment: `angle = double degree_to_radian(deg);` Remove the `double`. Same for the following two lines.

Comment: I suspect from what I'm seeing that you copied and pasted from the function declarations. Beware of copying and pasting in programming. It can lead to bugs, and it can lead to a few lines of bad code becoming a whole bunch of lines of bad code spread all over your programs.

Comment: @kaylum perfect I did that which caused a few more errors but after rearranging the order of the functions it seemed to work fine, thank you for the help